# Sort rows by number of columns

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an Excel document with more than 10 000 rows. 
Each row has a different number of columns . ..  I would need to find - somehow - a way to to sort this document by number of columns . . .  Example :

All the row with eight columns, then all the rows with six columns, etc,etc

Comment: Can a row contain blank cells in the middle of the data? If so, how do you define the number of columns for such a row?

Comment: COUNTA did it ! THank you :)